# Python function expected indented block, how?

Tags: python, function

```
import socket, thread, time

def main():
    #server()
    #client()

def client():
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall('Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    print 'Received', repr(data)

def server():
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        conn.sendall(data)
    conn.close()
```

> if **name** == "**main**":    main()   File "try.py", line 7
>       def client():
>         ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

What is the problem? Please answer if it is possible.

Comment: You have the body of your `main` function commented out.

Answer (score 13):

Your `main` function has no body. That's not allowed. If you want it to do nothing, use the `pass` statement.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above you do miss the `def main`.

As best practice you should use this format to make sure you are in the main process when executing the main.

You should get used to write the main in the following format:

```
def main():
    # my code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will prevent the main from being executed when your script is imported as module.

Comment: The OP's code has exactly that form. (The fact is somewhat obscured by a formatting screwup.) The only problem is that there is no (uncommented) code in the body of `main`.

Comment: I agree, I wanted to emphasis the need to verify that you are in the "main" process itself. Thank you.